# How to pass sqlParameterCollection to Command Object

Tags: c#

I have a Command object like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
```

How can I build the sqlParameterCollection in another routine and pass this collection to this Command object?

I have this code:

```
private SqlParameterCollection BuildParameters()
{
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();

    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@year", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 2013;

    return cmd2.Parameters;
}
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
cmd1.Parameters = BuildParameters();
```

Comment: Replaced the product tag as this question is not really about SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

The SqlCommand.Parameters property is read only so you cannot assign an SqlParameterCollection  object to it.

You may want to return an SqlParameter array from BuildParameters thus:

```
    private SqlParameter[] BuildParameters()
    {
        SqlParameter[] para = new SqlParameter[3];
        para[0] = new SqlParameter("@year", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = 2013 };
        return para;
    }
```

Then you can do the following:-

```
   SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
    cmd1.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd1.Parameters.AddRange(BuildParameters());
```

Comment: Hm. So I can use a SqlParameter array as a work around. Or perhaps I can pass the whole Command object, not only it's parameter collection?

Comment: Yes you can pass the `SqlCommand` object as a parameter into the `BuildParameters` method. Not sure how you wish to use/re-use this method as it appears you have the parameter hard-coded in the `BuildParameter` method. Does this mean you want the Parameters for the `SqlCommand` object you pass in to always be the same?

Answer (score 0):

you could handle this as an extension method, but honestly I don't know really how useful this would be

```
public static IEnumerable<IDbDataParameter> BuildParameters(this IDbCommand command, params KeyValuePair<string, DbType>[] parameters)
{
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, DbType> kvpParam in parameters)
    {
        IDbDataParameter param = command.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = kvpParam.Key;
        param.DbType = kvpParam.Value;
        yield return param;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple iterate throught the collection.

```
foreach (var mysqlParamater in oMySqlParameterCollection)
        {
            oMySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(mysqlParamater);
        }
```

I have written a method that accept mysqlparamater collection along with SP name you can use it as below:-

```
public int ExecuteNonQuery(MySqlParameterCollection oMySqlParameterCollection, string storedProcedure)
    {
        int affectedRows = 0;
        _oMySqlConnection.Open();
        MySqlCommand oMySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            CommandText = storedProcedure,
            Connection = _oMySqlConnection
        };
        foreach (var mysqlParamater in oMySqlParameterCollection)
        {
            oMySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(mysqlParamater);
        }
        affectedRows = oMySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        _oMySqlConnection.Close();
        return affectedRows;
    }
```